# Библиотека matplotlib: построение графика функции вида |y| = f(x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, matplotlib, графики

Всем привет. Как построить график для функции |y| = 1-x. График должен выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выполнении данного кода выводится неправильный график.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-40, 40, 10000)
y = 1 - x
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('График функции |y|  = 1 - x')
plt.ylabel('Ось y')
plt.xlabel('Ось x')
plt.grid()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -4, 10]) 
plt.plot(x, abs(y))
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как его исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать наоборот - выразить `x` через `y`, тогда вы сможете нарисовать этот график.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = np.linspace(-40, 40, 10000)
x = 1 - np.abs(y)
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('График функции |y|  = 1 - x')
plt.ylabel('Ось y')
plt.xlabel('Ось x')
plt.grid()
plt.axis([-10, 10, -4, 10]) 
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как выразить x через y в функции |y| = x^2-2x-3?

Comment: @Klef Тут уже по-другому, наверное, придётся действовать. Например, перебрать какой-то диапазон значений `x`, взять только такие значения из них, которые дают значение выражения >= 0 и сделать сразу две точки y = f(x) и y = -f(x). В общем, лучше задайте новый вопрос, я там отвечу